# Voltando informações gravadas no banco

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, delphi-7

Tenho um sistema que está instalado em uma rede instável, minha dúvida é o seguinte, se em algum momento na minha gravação eu perder a conexão com o banco de dados, como eu faço para desfazer  o que foi feito no banco de dados? Se eu colocar:

```
try
 ....
 query1.post;
 query2.post;
 commit;
except
 rollback;
```

Isso funcionaria? Acho que não, pois se no segundo Post, eu perder a conexão com o banco o rollback também não vai funcionar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim vai, você tem que estar em uma transação para isso, é claro. Mesmo que não consiga executar o `rollback`, o `commit` também não será executado e é somente no `commit` que as informações são salvas. Como a conexão foi interrompida sem informar ao banco, ele provavelmente irá segurar a conexão e a transação, até estourar o timeout, então ele mesmo irá descartar tudo.

Esse é o principio da *Atomicidade* que deve existir nos mecanismos de banco de dados: https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190612%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 3):

Você deve iniciar uma transação

Considerando

dbConexao - o nome do componente de conexão ao banco
query1 e query 2 - query com instruções em sql.

```
dbConexao.starttransaction;
Try
  Query1.execsql;
  Query2.execsql;

  dbConexao.commit;
except
  dbconexao.rollback;
end;
```

Pode haver variação dos comandos se for dbexpress, firedac ou outro. Mas esta é a sequencia correta dos comandos.

Answer (score 0):

Faz um tempo que não programo em Delhi, mas acho que seria mais ou menos assim:

```
qry1.post
qry2.post
...
qryN.post

try:
   commit
except
   Implmentação
```